# Where is the Nissan Rogue purge valve?

Tags: nissan, purge-solenoid, rogue

Friend has a 08/09 Nissan Rogue with the check engine light on.  Ran my OBD2 scanner on it and pulled a single code, P0444, which indicates per my search the Purge Control Solenoid Valve.  When I search for this my results are typically for the Nissan Altima.  So is the PCSV located under the car on the charcoal canister or in the engine bay?  When I do find the valve can it be ohm'd with a meter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under the hood on the right side of engine compartment. Unplug the connector, figure out which side is the computer controlled ground. Backprobe the ground wire. put a vacuum pump on it and ground the solenoid. Do this when the engine is hot and do it several times.

Check per tsb ntb05-053 as well. It covers harness rub through by the wiper motor setting any of 6 evap codes including p0444.

Spec on the solenoid is 35 ohms with no mention of temperature.

[image]

[image]

Comment: BY chance do you know the ohm readings I should be looking for to indicate a good or bad solenoid?

Comment: @Darth_Vader It doesn't specify a temperature but it should be 35 ohms.

Comment: Do you have a picture on it in the engine bay?  Ive looked at several locations and cant determine where it is and where you suggested appears to be a different type of canister then ive seen on trucks.

Comment: @Darth_Vader I added a picture out of a service manual. F32 in the diagram I circled it.